# qmake does not work on image on yocto image

Tags: qt, qmake, yocto

Using the new jethro from Yocto and the new qt5.5 when i build the multimedia image and include qt5-base and all the extra qt packages. when i try to use qmake on the image it returns an error:

```
root@genericx86:~/test# qmake test.pro
Could not find qmake configuration file linux-oe-g++.
```

the odd thing is when i run qmake -query it list two values and has my build path.

```
QT_SYSROOT:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX/raw:/usr
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib/qt5
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA/raw:/usr/lib/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/share/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DATA/raw:/usr/share/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/share/doc/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DOCS/raw:/usr/share/doc/qt5
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/include/qt5
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS/raw:/usr/include/qt5
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBS/raw:/usr/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib/qt5/libexec
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/libexec
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/bin/qt5
QT_INSTALL_BINS/raw:/usr/bin/qt5
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/share/qt5/tests
QT_INSTALL_TESTS/raw:/usr/share/qt5/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib/qt5/plugins
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib/qt5/imports
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/imports
QT_INSTALL_QML:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib/qt5/qml
QT_INSTALL_QML/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/share/qt5/translations
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS/raw:/usr/share/qt5/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/etc/qt5
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION/raw:/etc/qt5
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/share/qt5/examples
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES/raw:/usr/share/qt5/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/share/qt5/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS/raw:/usr/share/qt5/examples
QT_HOST_PREFIX:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr
QT_HOST_DATA:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib/qt5
QT_HOST_BINS:/usr/bin/qt5
QT_HOST_LIBS:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/genericx86/usr/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:/home/bbb/poky-jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++
QMAKE_XSPEC:linux-oe-g++
QMAKE_VERSION:3.0
QT_VERSION:5.5.1
```

i did not have this issue with Fido and qt5.4

Comment: The standard Qt build does not have `linux-oe-g++` spec. Do you have that spec in the path `QMAKE_SPEC`? There is related recent patch https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase/0001-Add-linux-oe-g-platform.patch

Comment: I'm having the same issue for my own recipe under yocto jethro and qt 5.5.1 from the meta-qt5 layer. Could it be due to a bad dependency in my recipe? It might be possible since running bitbake multiple times "solved" the issue. Maybe one package wasn't installed yet when trying to build your/my recipe?

Comment: @OrestHera: I tried that particular patch applied on top of the jethro branch without success. I think though that it could be a problem with the DEPENDS/RDEPENDS of my recipe. I did change it to `DEPENDS = "qtbase qtdeclarative"` and `RDEPENDS_${PN} = "qtbase qtdeclarative"`. I also changed the `meta-qt5` branch to `master` (instead of `jethro`) and everything builds fine now...